# Why are Python webservers unstable?

Tags: python, sockets, webserver, wsgi

I'm developing an HTTP server based game in Python. The plan is to have as few dependencies as possible, so I wanted it to work without installing a standalone webserver (like Apache, Lighttpd or nginx). The problem is, it doesn't work.

I tried the following versions:

- BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer (+SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn)
- wsgiref.simple_server
- twisted.web.server

When put under heavy load (`siege -b -c 100 -t 30s`), they all partially failed with either

`[error] socket: read error Connection reset by peer sock.c:460: Connection reset by peer`

or

`[error] socket: -1313092800 address is unavailable.: Cannot assign requested address`

By partially I mean: some requests were served, some not.

On the other hand, when I tried Lighttpd + Flask (i.e. WSGI) or even Lighttpd + PHP (just as a control case), it works absolutely fine. Availability 100%, Concurrency 100%.

Because of the latter working versions, I suppose the problem is not `siege`, or running `siege` and the server on the same machine, or the machine itself (Ubuntu 12.04 by the way).

NOTE: in all cases I tested simple "hello world" servers to minimize the possiblity of bugs.

So my two question:

1. *Why* are Python webservers unstable? (What exactly is the *cause*, not the solution?)
2. Is using a standalone webserver + Python the only/best solution (if I stick to Python), or am I missing something?

Comment: I'd guess the downvote is because this question is a bit outside the scope of stackoverflow - I think it would fit better in [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: @Brionius It turned out, it doesn't make sense. I was sent back *here* with a few downvotes... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my two question:
>   Why are Python webservers unstable? (What exactly is the cause, not the solution?)

The problem here is the word *unstable*.
You're reaching the implementation limit of the server process. This doesn't necessarily means it's unstable.
It's like pushing your car to its limit. When there's no more speed you can gain would you say your car is unstable?

This is a typical problem of "finding the good tool for the right job".
One thing is the application server and another is serving a large amount of requests and handling connection pooling. The latter is a task handled by (web)servers like nginx, lighttpd, apache, uwsgi which are built to deal with the concurrency and routing.

In detail, the servers you tried are built to handle a maximum amount of requests. After that limit is reached they drop connections. They's not built to en queue the connection for later.

If you never tried, take a look also at [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/), it's good for game servers.

> Is using a standalone webserver + Python the only/best solution (if I stick to Python), or am I missing something?

Yes. It's the best solution and not only for Python. It's a common design pattern. You'd see the same approach even in Ruby, PHP, Java.. 
The most common task is to distribute load across a cluster of application servers.

A typical environment is:

```
USER -> BALANCER (nginx,apache,ecc) -> APPSERVER (uwsgi, twisted, gunicorn, ..) -> WSGI Application
```

Comment: So basically what is missing is connection pooling? And *theoretically* one could build a Python script to handle that? (Not as a best solution, just to understand the problem more.)

Comment: Conn pooling is bigger than it seems. There's the c10k problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem And yes, it could be handled, as said take a look at Tornado. Then there are still other problems, like memory footprint, the python GIL (so you'll start to serve requests in a multiprocess way)...